# Which is more efficient, getLogger(String name) or getLogger(Class clazz)?

Tags: java, performance, logging

I am using apache logger api for logging the messages, warnings, errors and exception. I find two methods in logger api to catch the logging name.

```
public static Logger getLogger(String name)

public static Logger getLogger(Class clazz)
```

among those which is best methods to choose for performance?

Comment: Wnat do you assume there is a "best" one?

Comment: public static Logger getLogger(Class clazz) if we choose this we have to pass class, again there is reflection mechanism have to take place, which is weight to jvm right.

Comment: @Damodar: Some people wouldn't say that performance is the most important aspect of software.

Comment: if your app doesnot provide speed, then users will not attract to your application.when we have a heavy traffic to that software, then performance will come into picture

Comment: @Damodar: Sure, but you didn't state in your question that you need performance. You just asked for "best", which is totally subjective.

Comment: There's going to be practically no difference in performance here. If this is your critical performance issue, I'd be very interested in what you're doing!

Comment: @Niklas, i have tagged it to performance from the begging :)

Comment: @ControlAltDel not only that degrades the app there are many, but it was used in every class, so every time reflection mechanism is used . So iam thinking to use other constructor rather than this. Please suggest.

Comment: @Damodar: So you have measured and concluded that it impacts your performance too much? Or are you just guessing?

Comment: @NiklasB. iam gussing it

Comment: 1- These are not constructors but factory methods.
2- There is not a real different in performances of these 2 methods.
3- Most of the loggers behind Apache Commons Logging using singletons for each Logger.
4- I believe the `Class` constructor uses `getName()` method to fetch fully qualified class name.
5- If you want a little performance gain use slf4j which uses static binding instead of dynamic binding.

Comment: @Damodar: Then this falls under premature optimization. You should actually profile your application to find out what the bottlenecks are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, logger instances are created as static fields. So this call is only made once per class per JVM, and the performance difference will be in the noise.

It's hard to see a good reason to do otherwise. If you are going to call the one that takes a class, you are making one logger per class, and so you can't possibly be sitting in a loop.

So you can expect the one that takes a class to be faster, but you will be hard-pressed to measure the difference in a realistic situation.

Comment: If you use Log4j as the backing logging framework, you should know that it supports categories which are not class names, and it supports sub-categories for them, so I believe it calls `getName()` on classes not vice verse.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh yes of course, but it's not all that common to use them. And the OP offered up the Class form as an option, which precludes them.